# Custom domain for users in a SASS

Tags: laravel, nginx, subdomain, nuxt.js, cname

I am building a SASS project (SPA) using Laravel and Nuxtjs.
Let's say my application provides news portal
So, a customer buys a subscription at www.example.com,

1) I want to provide them a **subdomain** based on their username(eg. user1.example.com), where they can show their news which actually is served from www.example.com

2) Also, I want to facilitate customers with custom domain feature. So that, they can have their **own domain** (eg. www.user1.com) where their news will show but again everything will be served from www.example.com

3) Another thing is, any user **Logs In** user1.example.com (eg. to make a comment or rate a news) they will be logged in any other subdomain(eg. user2.example.com, www.user1.com) in the same browser.

How would you suggest to solve this problem?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hey Abdur, have you already got an answer to this? I want to do roughly the same, but it turns out to be more difficult than expected..

Comment: @ralphjsmit
I have done it other way.